# How to fix Slimmenu multi level sub items going out of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using slimmenu for my website. but unfortunately submenu is going out of my desktop screen if there have nested child items. So i tried to add a class "edge" with'ul' when it will go out of screen.

Here is the screenshot of the preview where i used the code https://codepen.io/themeix/pen/gyxGNO

But my code doesn't work. Here is my HTML code.

```
<div class="main-menu-area">
   <div class="logo-area">
      <h1>My Logo  </h1>
   </div>
   <div class="menu-warpper">
      <div class="navigation-navbar">
         <ul id="navigation" class="slimmenu">
            <li><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Main Item</a></li>
            <li>
               <a href="#">Main Item</a>
               <ul>
                  <li>
                     <a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a>
                     <ul>
                        <li>
                           <a href="#">Sub Menu 2</a>
                           <ul>
                              <li>
                                 <a href="#">Sub Menu 3</a>
                                 <ul>
                                    <li>
                                       <a href="#">Sub Menu 4</a>
                                       <ul>
                                          <li>
                                             <a href="#">Sub Menu 5</a>
                                             <ul>
                                                <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 6</a></li>
                                             </ul>
                                          </li>
                                       </ul>
                                    </li>
                                 </ul>
                              </li>
                           </ul>
                        </li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
                  <li><a href="#">Sub Menu 1</a></li>
               </ul>
            </li>
         </ul>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried the following js code to inject  a class edge but unfortunately its adding for all the ul when sub menu items going out of the screen.. I want to inject only for the specific ($this) submenu item when it goes out of the screen.

```
jQuery(".slimmenu li").on('mouseenter mouseleave', function(e) {
    if (jQuery('ul', this).length) {
        var elm = jQuery('ul:first', this);
        var off = elm.offset();
        var l = off.left;
        var w = elm.width();
        var docH = jQuery(".navigation-navbar").height();
        var docW = jQuery(".navigation-navbar").width();
        var isEntirelyVisible = (l + w <= docW);
        if (!isEntirelyVisible) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('edge');
        } else {
            jQuery(this).removeClass('edge');
        }
    }
});
```

in that js code **edge** class adding for all the submenu items but **i want to inject it only for the current .has-submenu item while mousehove and its going out of the screen**. and **removeclass also not working** when i leave the mouse. Can anyone help me to  fix that issue for me by using js?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

remove your menu width....there is limited space between the nav link and that's why this was happened.

Comment: Yes.. i know.. but i used smaller width to show the problem. I actually want to fix that submenu visibility issue by js for any multi level dropdown